# Systemverilog sequence - want to check value of data the first time vld goes high?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

This was my first naive attempt. Basically `vld` can go high anytime in the 20 cycles. But the first time it goes high, `data` needs to be a specific value, say `'h20`.

```
sequence correct_vld_and_data;
    ##[1:20] vld
    ##0 (data == 'h20);
endsequence

property prop_correct_vld_and_data;
    @(posedge clk)
        (precondition_met) 
        -> 
        (correct_vld_and_data);
endproperty

assert prop_correct_vld_and_data;
```

The problem is, above sequence matches for the following case; but I *don't* want it to match, meaning I *do* want the assertion error to fire:

```
t=0    : precondition_met==1
t=1-4  : vld==0
t=5    : vld==1 data=='h5
t=6-9  : vld==0
t=10   : vld==1 data=='h20
t=11-20: vld==0
```

The first time that vld goes high, I *need* `data=='h20` and not `'h5` like it is this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use then the first match_operator like this :
(precondition_met) ##0 first_match(##[1:20] vld) |-> data == 'h20

Because in your example it has two matches :
  the first one when data=='h5
  the second one when data=='h20